# Listview not displaying below RelativeLayout

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-arrayadapter

ListView is not showing, any assistance is greatly appreciated! I am able to display products with ListView alone but I cannot figure out how to display it below my Relative Layout.

Cart.java:

```
 public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String user;
    static CartChangeListener cartChangeListener;
    ProductsAdapter adaptCart;
    ArrayList<Product> cartItems = new ArrayList<>();
    Menu menu;
    float total = (float)0.00;
    float shipCost = 15;
    float tax = (float)0.07;
    String URI;
    TextView subTotal;
    TextView shipping;
    TextView taxes;
    TextView totals;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_cart, null);
        //ListView.addHeaderView(headerView);
        user = MainActivity.currentAccount.getUsername();
        if(user == null || user.equals("Guest")) {
            shipCost = (float)0.00;
            tax = (float)0.00;
        }
        if(user != null && !(user.equals("Guest"))) {
            new getCartIcon().execute();
            //View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_cart, null);
            //View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_search, null);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_cart_view);
            new returnCartItems().execute();
            //if (!(cartItems.isEmpty())) {
                adaptCart = new ProductsAdapter(Cart.this, 0, cartItems);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                        try {
                            ProductsAdapter.ViewHolder holder = new ProductsAdapter.ViewHolder();
                            holder.product_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
                            holder.product_dept = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_dept);
                            holder.product_desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
                            holder.product_price = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
                            holder.product_qty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_qty);
                            holder.product_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);

                            URI = "http://www.michaelscray.com/Softwear/graphics/";
                            String dept = "Dept: ";
                            String money = "$";
                            String qty = "Qty: ";
                            URI += cartItems.get(position).getProduct_img();
                            Uri uris = Uri.parse(URI + cartItems.get(position).getProduct_img());
                            URI uri = java.net.URI.create(URI);
                            holder.product_name.setText(cartItems.get(position).getProduct_name());
                            holder.product_desc.setText(cartItems.get(position).getProduct_desc());
                            holder.product_dept.setText(dept + cartItems.get(position).getProduct_dept());
                            holder.product_price.setText(money + String.valueOf(cartItems.get(position).getPrice()));
                            holder.product_qty.setText(qty + String.valueOf(cartItems.get(position).getProduct_qty()));
                            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(URI).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.product_img);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                listView.setAdapter(adaptCart);
            //}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        this.menu = menu;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        return true;
    }

    public class getCartIcon extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String tempUser = user;
        int cartNum = 0;
        float tempTotal;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            subTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_subTotal);
            shipping = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_shipping);
            totals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_total);
            taxes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_taxes);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            if(tempUser != null) {
                try {
                    Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
                    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE `User_Name` = '" + tempUser + "'";

                    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
                    //st.setString(1, tempUser);

                    final ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(queryString);

                    while (result.next()) {
                        try {
                            tempTotal += result.getFloat("Price");
                            //skus.add(result.getInt("SKU"));
                        } catch(SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        cartNum++;
                        //setTotal(result.getFloat(String.valueOf("Price")));
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            getCartItems(cartNum);
            subTotal.setText(String.valueOf(tempTotal));
            shipping.setText(String.valueOf(shipCost));
            tax = tempTotal * tax;
            taxes.setText(String.valueOf(tax));
            totals.setText(String.valueOf(tempTotal + shipCost + tax));
            //setTotal(tempTotal);
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    public class returnCartItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String tempUser = user;
        Product product = null;
        List<Integer> skus = new ArrayList<>();
        //String descr = "DETAILS: \n\n";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            if(tempUser != null) {
                try {
                    Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
                    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE `User_Name` = '" + tempUser + "'";

                    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
                    //st.setString(1, tempUser);

                    final ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(queryString);

                    while (result.next()) {
                        try {
                            skus.add(result.getInt("SKU"));
                        } catch(SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
                    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM Inventory";

                    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
                    //st.setString(1, tempUser);

                    final ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(queryString);

                    while (result.next()) {
                        for(int i=0; i < skus.size(); i++) {
                            if(skus.get(i) == result.getInt("SKU")) {
                                product = new Product();
                                product.setProduct_name(result.getString("Name"));
                                product.setProduct_dept(result.getString("Department"));
                                product.setProduct_desc(result.getString("Description"));
                                product.setPrice(result.getFloat("Price"));
                                product.setProduct_qty(result.getInt("Quantity"));
                                product.setProduct_img(result.getString("Image"));
                                cartItems.add(product);
                                /*
                                descr += "Product: " + result.getString("Name") + "\n" +
                                "Department: " + result.getString("Department") + "\n" +
                                "Price: $" + result.getFloat("Price") + "\n\n";
                                */
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    public void setTotal(float total) {
        this.total += total;
    }

    public float getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void getCartItems(int cart) {

        MenuItem cartMenuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
        if (cart == 0) {
            cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart0);
        }
        if (cart == 1) {
            cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart1);
        }
        if (cart == 2) {
            cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart2);
        }
        if (cart == 3) {
            cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart3);
        }
        if (cart == 4) {
            cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart4);
        }
        if (cart == 5) {
            cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart5);
        }
        if (cart > 5) {
            cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart5plus);
        }
        if (cart > 10) {
            cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart10plus);
        }
    }
    }
```

ProductsAdapter.java:

```
public class ProductsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Product> products;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    String money = "$";
    String dept = "Dept: ";
    String qty ="Qty: ";
    static String URI;


    public ProductsAdapter(Activity activity, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Product> product) {
        super(activity, textViewResourceId, product);
        try {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.products = product;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationActivity());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    public Product getItem(Product position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView product_name;
        public TextView product_desc;
        public TextView product_dept;
        public TextView product_price;
        public TextView product_qty;
        public ImageView product_img;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        try {
            if(convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.product_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
                holder.product_dept = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_dept);
                holder.product_desc = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
                holder.product_price = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
                holder.product_qty = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_qty);
                holder.product_img = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                vi.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }
            URI = "http://www.michaelscray.com/Softwear/graphics/";
            URI += products.get(position).getProduct_img();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(URI + products.get(position).getProduct_img());
            holder.product_name.setText(products.get(position).getProduct_name());
            holder.product_desc.setText(products.get(position).getProduct_desc());
            holder.product_dept.setText(dept + products.get(position).getProduct_dept());
            holder.product_price.setText(money + String.valueOf(products.get(position).getPrice()));
            holder.product_qty.setText(qty + String.valueOf(products.get(position).getProduct_qty()));
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(URI).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.product_img);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }

        return vi;
    }

}
```

And, activity_cart.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llSliderCart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#5e80ab"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary"
            android:layout_width="254dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CART SUMMARY"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkout_btn" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Checkout"
            android:id="@+id/checkout_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cart_rows"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Subtotal"
            android:textColor="#a4a4a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/vertical_divider_welcome" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/currency"
            android:textColor="#a4a4a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_subTotal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:textColor="#a4a4a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/vertical_divider_welcome" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cart_rows"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Shipping"
            android:textColor="#a4a4a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/vertical_divider_welcome" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/currency"
            android:textColor="#a4a4a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_shipping"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:textColor="#a4a4a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/vertical_divider_welcome" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cart_rows"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Tax"
            android:textColor="#a4a4a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/vertical_divider_welcome" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/currency"
            android:textColor="#a4a4a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#a4a4a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
            android:id="@+id/textView_taxes" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/vertical_divider_welcome" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cart_rows"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_title" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/vertical_divider_welcome" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/currency"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_total"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_title" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/vertical_divider_welcome" />

    <!--
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Description"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
    -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cart contents:"
            android:id="@+id/contents"
            android:background="@color/vertical_divider_welcome"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/list_cart_view">
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

While your `RelativeLayout`(the one just before the `ListView`) have `match_parent` as height, it will take the remaining space of the window... so there is no place for your `ListView` to be shown.

Comment: I have changed the height to the respective RelativeLayout to wrap_content and it is still not showing anything with the ListView. Thank your for your comment!

Comment: The **sum** of your layout childrens height is greater than the screen height, this is why your list still not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Give id to the above Relative layout and use the same below.

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/"
        android:id="@+id/list_cart_view">
    </ListView>
```

Comment: I am now getting the error: " Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout:layout_below". Thanks for your comment!

Comment: It's parent is Linearlayout?

Comment: Yes, would that have to be changed?

Comment: NO, you will have to then make many moifications. android:layout_height="wrap_content" ,  use this property in all of your LinearLayouts or android:layout_height="match_parent" in the root linear Layout.